# gendef returning invalid syntax error

Tags: installation, theano

I am trying to install Theano for machine learning on my Windows 7 computer.

One of the last steps in installing the dependencies is to 'create a link library for GCC' by 'Opening up the Python shell and cd to C:\SciSoft. Then execute:

```
gendef WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\python27.dll
dlltool --dllname python27.dll --def python27.def --output-lib WinPython-
64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\libs\libpython27.a
```

I've tried doing this but I get a invalid syntax error highlighted on 'WinPython'. I tried changing directory to go deeper and running gendef again and it also returned the same error. This is a copy and paste job from http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/install_windows.html#install-windows

Comment: Does the `WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4` directory exist inside `C:\SciSoft`? Or any similar directory but with a different version number.

Comment: Hi Daniel, thank you for your answer, the problem was in fact I opened a python GUI shell instead of the one created from the env.bat file. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 1):

I also followed the tutorial at the link to install Theano.

The line "*Finally we need to create a link library for GCC. Open up the Python shell and cd to c:\SciSoft*" is probably an error; "the Python shell" should be modified to "cmd.exe".

The two-line scripts are not python scripts, and can be successfully run on cmd.exe after changing directory to c:\SciSoft.